# gpg No such file or directory

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to run gpg from a Bash script designed to backup a website.  The command that fails is

```
gpg --homedir /home/backupuser/.gnupg --verbose --no-tty --recipient {group-name} --trust-model always --output /home/backupuser/backup/{tar-file}.gpg --encrypt /mnt/ramdir/site-backup-backupuser/{tar-file}
```

It fails with return code 127.  The gpg home directory exists, as does the {tar-file}. The output directory exists but the output file does not.

If I repeat the gpg command in the script it fails in exactly the same way. But if I execute it in shell immediately after it has failed in the script it works as expected.  The output is:

```
gpg: using subkey {hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} instead of primary key {hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh}
gpg: automatically retrieved '{email address1}' via Local
gpg: No trust check due to '--trust-model always' option
gpg: using subkey {hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} instead of primary key {hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh}
gpg: automatically retrieved '{email address2}' via Local
gpg: No trust check due to '--trust-model always' option
gpg: reading from '/mnt/ramdir/site-backup-backupuser/{tar-file}'
gpg: writing to '/home/backupuser/backup/{tar-file}.gpg'
gpg: '/mnt/ramdir/site-backup-backupuser/{tar-file}' already compressed
gpg: RSA/AES256 encrypted for: "{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} {Comment} <{email address1}>"
gpg: RSA/AES256 encrypted for: "{hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh} {Comment} <{email address2}>"
```

This is Debian "bullseye" 11.6, gpg 2.2.27 and libgcrypt 1.8.8.

I have tried numerous combinations of parameters, always with the above result.  With or without --homedir, with or without sudo (I was getting desperate), from a file on disk rather than in RAM, with or without --verbose and several others.

Comment: It doesn't look like it failed.

Comment: Sorry if I have confused you.  It fails when I run gpg in the script.  The message is the entire command line, followed by ": No such file or directory".  And gpg exits with return code 127.   When I execute the command outside the script it succeeds, with the output shown.  I want it to work in the script.

Comment: I eventually found a workaround to this problem; I hope this helps anyone else suffering the same failure.  I placed the gpg command in a second script file which I invoked from the first one.  This allowed gpg to perform correctly.